# asp:listbox loosing value on auto postback

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an asp list box that is populated from the code behind

```
    <asp:ListBox ID="UploadsApprovedCountries" EnableViewState="true"  runat="server" Rows="1" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedCountryChange"></asp:ListBox>

    protected void Load_Countries()
    {
        ListItem ps = new ListItem("Please select", "");
        ps.Value = "";
        UploadsApprovedCountries.Items.Add(ps);



        foreach (string cntry in Countries.CountriesArray())
        {
            UploadsApprovedCountries.Items.Add(new ListItem(cntry, cntry));
        }
    }
```

and in my Page_Load I call it like this

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Load_Countries();
        }
```

and on autopostback calls this method

```
    protected void SelectedCountryChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filter = UploadsApprovedCountries.SelectedItem.Value;
        Response.Write("line 589");
    }
```

However nothing I seem to do ever actually calls this method. The filter string is never populated and "Line 589" is never wrote out.

Can anyone help out

the whole of my asp.net page

```
asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentMainBody" ID="LocalMainBody" runat="server">
<h1> administration</h1>
<div class="clearboth"></div>
    <div>
    <div class="demo">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Uploads awaiting approval</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Uploads approved</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Sign-ups awaiting approval</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Sign-ups approved</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Rejected</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-5">
        <h2>Rejected submissions</h2>
        <div id="rejectedSubmissions" runat="server">

        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-1">
        <h2>Uploads awaiting approval</h2>
        <div id="matUnautherised" runat="server">
        </div>
         <div class="clearboth"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
           <h2>Uploads live on site</h2>
        <asp:ListBox ID="UploadsApprovedCountries" EnableViewState="true"  runat="server" Rows="1" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedCountryChange" OnTextChanged="SelectedCountryChange"></asp:ListBox>
        <div id="matAutherised" runat="server">
        </div>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-2">
        <h2>Sign-ups awaiting approval</h2>
        <div id="signups" runat="server">

        </div>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-4">
        <h2>Sign-ups live on site</h2>
        <div id="signupsapproved" runat="server">


        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
     </div>

      </div>
```

I have just noticed that if I change my code in my listbox to this

```
            <asp:ListBox ID="UploadsApprovedCountries" EnableViewState="true"  runat="server" Rows="1" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedCountryChange">
                <asp:ListItem Value="test1" Text="test1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="test2" Text="test2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="test3" Text="test3"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="test4" Text="test4"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="test5" Text="test5"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>
```

and don't populate it from the data source then it works as it should. Is there a difference between adding the items from the code behind and adding them directly like above?

Comment: Is the page posted back at all? Are you using a `RequredFieldValidator`? If so, show it. Have you set a breakpoint in `SelectedCountryChange`, does it get hit?

Comment: Are you using `UpdatePannel`?

Comment: Is the page posted back at all? Are you using a `RequredFieldValidator`? If so, show it.

Comment: your question isn't clear, adding your aspx page may help us

Comment: Hi there is no RequiredFieldValidator and the page does seem to post back, I'll add a breakpoint in the method, and let you know

Comment: I have just added System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() to it and it does nothing. Like its not even calling the method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338472/selectedindex-is-lost-during-postbacks-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

simple really once you know how

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Load_Countries();
        UploadsApprovedCountries.EnableViewState = true;
    }
```